# Jhipster : css on production environment at runtime differs from local dev environment

Tags: css, jhipster, bootbox

I am using bootbox to display a dialog box :

```
bootbox.confirm({
  message: "Confirmez-vous l'envoi de la demande de CRA ?",
  backdrop: false,
  className: "on-top-bootbox-alert-2",
  buttons: {
    confirm: {
        label: 'Oui',
        className: 'btn-success'
    },
    cancel: {
        label: 'Non',
        className: 'btn-danger'
    }
  },
```

In my main.css :

```
.on-top-bootbox-alert-2 {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

When I run the war (with dev and prod profile), the bootbox doesn't show because the z-index of on-top-bootbox-alert-2 has the value 7.

[image]

And when I click on main.css I am getting the value 9999.

[image]

The problem doesn't happen when I run the app from IntelliJ.

Is there something wrong with the build process? I am used to build this app since 2 years, and it's the first time I am getting this issue.

Comment: Have you been upgrading your jhipster? What version was it generated with? Have you tried outside intellij using maven /grade? Did you use to have that old value? Is it cached in intellij somehow? Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: I have looked to the minified css generated by gulp and the value of z-index is 7 whereas it should be 9999. Gulp seems to change the value during the build process. I have heard about disabling zindex minification  with cssnano task in gulp but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Editing build.js solved my problem :
`.pipe(cssnano)`
to

```
.pipe(cssnano,{
            zindex:false
        });
```